# How to run grep at one file in another avoiding memory exaust issue?

Tags: text-processing, grep, memory

Have here two large text files, about `30mb` each one, which would like to `grep` them one in another, as `grep -f "file01.txt" "file02.txt" > file03.txt`.

Doing so returns "memory exaust" error.

How could those files be compared disregarding alphabetic order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your `file01.txt` contains actual *regular expressions*, try:

```
grep -Ff "file01.txt" "file02.txt" > file03.txt
```

`-F` tells `grep` to treat `file01.txt` as fixed strings, not regular expressions.  This will both greatly increase the speed and greatly reduce the memory requirements.

#### Regular Expressions

Alternatively, if your `file01.txt` really does contain regular expressions, you can split it into parts and apply `grep` to each part separately:

```
split -dn 10 "file01.txt" ./tmp-file01.
for f in ./tmp-file01.*; do grep -f "$f" "file02.txt"; done >file03.txt
```

The above splits `file01.txt` into 10 parts.  Depending on your available memory, you may need more than that.

If file01.txt does *not* have regexes, then use `-F` in the second line:

```
for f in ./tmp-file01.*; do grep -Ff "$f" "file02.txt"; done >file03.txt
```

Comment: They haven't regexes. First answer using `grep -Ff` option returned `Killed` error, the second one spliting first files is in 4th file, should complete without error. Furthermore its using `CPU` instead o `Mem`, as being monitored via `htop`.

Comment: Very good.  Also, if there are no regexes, then using `-F` will help speed up the second approach also.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - pattern must be loaded into `grep` and this exaust memory.

But if you want to **compare** files, why don't you simply use `diff` (after sorting the contents)?

For the one-line per pattern (like list of MD5s):

```
while read md5; do
    grep -w "$md5" file02.txt
done < file01.txt > file03.txt
```

This of course is much slower, especially with big file02.txt (when it doesn't fit into cache), but works for every size of the pattern file01.txt.

Comment: Couldn't use `diff` due mixed order contents.

Comment: What's the problem with sorting the files before? What are the patterns inside "file01.txt", are those really patterns, or just words or lines you want to grep?

Comment: They're several `md5sum` of files, as one have `01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 38, 06` content, the other have `01, 02, 03, 03, 03, 08, 07, 06, 83, 38, 12, 01, 05, 06`. When first line gets out of order, the comparison lost its due.

Comment: @Renan41 Hi, it seems to be an [XYproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) [`:-)`](https://xkcd.com/974/)  <- Click here. You have 2 files with md5sum and filenames. You will have different groups (only in file1, only in file2, same md5sum in file1 and 2 for the same filename, for different filenames, different md5sum for the same filename... plus complications due to different paths). Post your final goal as question and you may receive even more useful answers.

Comment: The selected answer achieved main goal, which worked out fine.